# grep through binary file

Tags: regex, grep

I have a binary file that contains lines in the following form:

```
blabla^A2013.04.03-09:35:04^Ablabla
```

where `^A` is the binary character `001`.

I want to be able to perform a grep that will give me only what is between the `^A` (not the whole line).

I know that flag `-o` is only for match but I don't know how to search for that binary character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to include control-A on the command line by simply typing <kbd>control-A</kbd> where you want it to appear.  At worst, you might need to type <kbd>control-V</kbd> before it.  You can also explore notations using `bash`'s [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) such as `$'\001'`.

Comment: nice! we are getting closer. the `control-V control-A` did the trick so now I can find the first ^A but how I find the ending one? I tried `grep -o "^A*^A"` but it is not what I ment: ^A than anything until another ^A

Comment: got it. I used: `^A[^^A]*^A`

Comment: You'd need `grep -o "^A[^^A]*^A" or thereabouts; this will pick up the control-A's at each end.  I would be tempted to use `sed` instead of `grep` for this: `sed 's/.*^A\([^^A]*\)^A.*/\1/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
grep --binary-files=text pattern file.txt
```

so :

```
$ grep --binary-files=text -oP '\^\K[^\^]+(?=\^)' file.txt
A2013.04.03-09:35:04
```

Comment: but what is the pattern? I tried `^A` and `001` and `\001` non of them worked